# Is there a way to use wildcards with '=' in the nested document in x devapi

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-x-devapi

I have this data

```
{
    "a": "bar",
    "b": {
        "b1": 6,
        "b2": 7,
        "b3": {
            "b1": 99,
            "b2": 98,
            "b3": {
                "b1": 999,
                "b2": 998
            }
        }
    },
    "_id": "000061313aa10000000000000001"
}
{
    "a": "baz",
    "b": {
        "b1": 1,
        "b2": 7
    },
    "_id": "000061313aa10000000000000002"
}
{
    "a": "bbr",
    "c": 37,
    "_id": "0000613247ed0000000000000001"
}
```

How can I perform a search on the documents using find on the nested arrays usign "="?

Based on documentation, this works "'99' IN $**.b1 && '98' IN $**.b2".

The problem is how can I do this exact same search using the = like this "$**.b1 = '99' && $**.b2 = '98'"

Actual need would need to be able to search and compare timestamps and make more complex search requirments directly on the nested arrays.